# Как получить индекс позиции при горизонтальном прокручивание RecyclerView?

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview, position

В приложении есть горизонтальный RecyclerView в котором происходит выбор карточки в виде карусели, где главный элемент занимает центральную позицию. Как можно получить индекс текущей позиции объекта при свайпе?

[image: Пример RecyclerView из объектов, которые имеют каждый свой цвет, при прокручивании нужно получить номер объекта, чтобы узнать его цвет]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Позицию можно получить в адаптере, через метод отрисовки элемента списка:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MessageHolder, position: Int) {
```

и дальше передавать в активность/фрагмент при клике. Либо можно через слушатель `OnScrollListener` у `RecyclerView`:

```
myList.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                    if (dx > 0) {
                        val visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.childCount
                        val totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.itemCount
                        val pastVisibleItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()



                    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
                }
            })
```

Comment: Если использую findFirstVisibleItemPosition()+1, то работает все кроме самого первого элемента
Если использую findLastVisibleItemPosition()-1, то работает все кроме самого последнего элемента

Answer (score 1):

> *Позицию можно получить в адаптере, через метод отрисовки элемента списка:*

**В адаптере передается следующий готовящийся элемент, а не текущий**

> *и дальше передавать в активность/фрагмент при клике.*

**По клику можно получить, но хочется по скролингу**

> *Либо можно через слушатель `OnScrollListener` у `RecyclerView`:*

**Через OnScrollListener по какой то причине передается 5 событий подряд, хотелось бы уловить самое последние состояние**

```
'''kotlin
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
if (dx > 0) {
val itemPosition = mLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition()-1
/Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "itemPosition: $itemPosition", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
})
'''
```

addOnScrollListener нашел только у mRecyclerView. И для текущей позиции больше подходит похоже findLastVisibleItemPosition.
Благодарю за ответ.